# How to change the home directory of hudson?

Tags: hudson

I deployed hudson.war in the sun application server 9.1. I like to check how can i change the home directory of hudson to point to another directory becasue if using a .hudson directory is not ok as i have very little diskspace left in main disk drive.

Answer (score 2):

See: [Administering Hudson](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Administering+Hudson)

I pass the following:

```
-DHUDSON_HOME=path/to/hudson
```

to my container (Tomcat).

Answer (score 2):

1. Start button
2. Right-click "Computer", then Properties
3. Click Advanced System Settings
4. Click Environment Variables
5. Under "System Variables" click New..., and make a new variable called HUDSON_HOME.  Set this to your desired directory.

Now create a new CMD.EXE and launch Hudson, or restart Tomcat and Hudson will use the new directory.